# facebook javascript json

Tags: javascript, json, facebook

I would like to assign document.height to the variable `H`, how can I accomplish this?

```
var H = document.height;
var p = { width: 520, height: H };
FB.Canvas.setSize(p);
```

How would I do this in javascript? Was it correct expression `height: H`? It didn't work.

Comment: `"2200"` is **not** the same as `2200`.

Comment: I rewrote var H = document.height;

Comment: I think `2200` becomes a string when it is written as `"2200"` try `var H = 2200; var p = {width: 520, height:H}; FB.Canvas.setSize(p);`

Comment: @msaif While you are editing your question, please also correct the formatting. You've asked enough questions here to know how this works by now.

Comment: var H = 2200; var p = {width: 520, height:H}; FB.Canvas.setSize(p); OK but i like to assign document.Height to the var H how can I?

Comment: @msaif Please edit your question. That is what people will answer. Not your comment.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? are you sure the FB JS library is loaded by the time you are calling the `setSize` method?

Answer (score 1):

If :

```
alert(typeof(document.height));
```

alerts "number";

Your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've never written any JavaScript for Facebook, so what follows is an educated **guess**.

Facebook are probably running your JavaScript within an `iframe` sandbox for security reasons. A brief look at [Google results](http://www.google.com/search?q=facebook%20javascript%20sandbox) also seems to suggest that they pre-process your code before running it, to "sanitize" it by removing security issues, access to banned DOM APIs etc.

Given this reasonable assumption, two reasons why your code is not working come to mind:

1. Your access of the `document` object is banned for security reasons, so removed from your sanitized script or disabled in some way.
2. `document` refers to the [`HTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLDocument) rendered in the `iframe` within which your JavaScript is running, in which case `height` will be the height of this `iframe`, not the entire Facebook page as you are probably expecting.

Do any Facebook developer tools help here? Are there any errors logged in your console?